# Move Shapes in x-axis with OnMouseMoved on canvas in JavaFX

Tags: canvas, javafx

I create `Shape` and I need to `move` in `horizontal position` on a `Canvas`, that is, on the `x-axis`, without using `timeline`

`Class Square` to draw a square and insert into a `canvas` position

```
public class Square{
    //calculate the position of the rand column to 
    //draw and insert in the position of the canvas
    public void drawSquare(GraphicsContext gc) {
        //Square Shadow 
        //gc.rect(posX, posY, w, h);
        gc.rect(1, 53, 50, 50);
        gc.fill();
        gc.beginPath();
        //Square
        gc.beginPath();
        gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.setLineWidth(2);
        //gc.rect(posX, posY, w, h);
        gc.rect(1, 53, 48, 48);
        gc.fill();
        gc.stroke();

    }
}
```

New `Canvas instance` with `height = 450` and `width = 600`

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.setHeight(450);
canvas.setWidth(600);
```

and `GraphicsContext` to `draw square`

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
```

The `shape` is `create` and `draw square`

```
Square square= new Square();
square.drawSquare(gc);
```

and the example of `drawSquare` with `canvas`

[image]

and the `mouse event` to `move square` on `canvas` on `X-Axis`, I made something
but it is not working, maybe can have another solution

```
canvas.setOnMouseMoved((MouseEvent event) -> {
 //select the square and move on x-axis
});
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is something else drawn on your `Canvas`? You could also be better off using [`Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html). If you're attaching a listener to your canvas, you will have to check that the mouse is on the rectangle by keeping track or where it was last drawn. Using a `Rectangle` will save you that hassle. Also, instead of drawing a `Path`, it would be much simpler to use the `GraphicsContext#strokeRect` method.

Comment: i wanted to say something, but i mind my own business. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (*based of MikaelF*)

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Rectangle rectBound = new Rectangle();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        Canvas c = new Canvas(400,400);

        root.setCenter(c);
        c.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            boolean shouldDraw = false;
            double dX,dY;

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if (arg0.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                    shouldDraw = rectBound.contains(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());
                    if (shouldDraw) {
                        dX = arg0.getX();
                        dY = arg0.getY();
                    }
                } else if (arg0.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                    if (shouldDraw) {
                        double x = (arg0.getX() + rectBound.getX() - dX),
                                y = (arg0.getY() + rectBound.getY() - dY);

                        c.getGraphicsContext2D().clearRect(rectBound.getX(),
                                rectBound.getY(), rectBound.getWidth(),//50
                                rectBound.getHeight());

                        rectBound.setY(y);
                        rectBound.setX(x);

                        dX = arg0.getX();
                        dY = arg0.getY();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        c.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);
        rectBound.xProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>(){//since they go together
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0,
                    Number arg1, Number arg2) {
                c.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect(rectBound.getX(),rectBound.getY(),
                        rectBound.getWidth(),rectBound.getHeight()); //just an example
            }

        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        rectBound.setWidth(50);rectBound.setHeight(50);
        rectBound.setY(50);rectBound.setX(10);//because of the listener x is last
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

It might be an alternative means, *beware this is a rough work*